# External HDDs are recognised only when waking up from sleep

Tags: windows-7, hard-drive, boot, external-hard-drive, sleep

I've started facing this issue pretty recently (less than 2 weeks). I have several external HDDs (all with separate power adapters) from different manufacturers.

### Case 1

> HDD connected prior to booting up

When I boot into my system with any of the HDDs connected, the windows boot hangs up at the copyright screen:

[image: screen]

The Windows logo doesn't load and I see a pink bar at the top of the screen, about 50 pixels in height. This happens 2-3 times (on forcing reboot with power button) and only after that does the OS load properly.

### Case 2

> HDD disconnected while booting. Connecting them afterwards.

When I connect the HDDs after a successful bootup, the OS fails to recognise any new hardware inserted. This **doesn't happen** when I connect *any other USB devices instead*. It is only the HDDs that are not being recognised normally.

### Case 3

> Connecting HDDs after putting system to sleep.

When the above failed, I put the system in sleep mode. Connected my HDD and woke it up again.

Surprisingly, it was able to recognise the HDDs now. The same behaviour is observed with all of my external HDDs.

Comment: Sounds like an issue with your USB drivers or BIOS. Have your drivers been updated recently, and does a rollback help?

Comment: Agree with @qasdfdsaq, try a rollback (system restore) to a point in time prior to when you were experiencing this issue because it's very difficult to troubleshoot. Is the PC infected? What make/model number is it? What version is the BIOS? Are you fairly knowledgeable when it comes to Device Manager?

Comment: Looks like a driver problem or some kind of software conflict.Try booting in [Safe mode](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-8/windows-startup-settings-safe-mode) or performing a [Clean Boot](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/929135) this could help tracking down the problem.

Comment: @Techpumpkin_WD Seems that booting in safe mode does not result in failure.

Comment: @edgerrr I turned off my system restore settings long ago (I desperately needed space). ASUS M5A97 running AMD 8320 processor. The device manager fails to recognise any newly connected hardwares even when I initiate a scan for the same.